# How do I combine two typed Joi schemas?

Tags: typescript, joi

I have two interfaces, where the second extends the first:

```
interface Basic { 
  key: string;
}

interface User extends Basic {
  firstName: string;
}
```

And I use Joi schemas for validation. For the interface `Basic` there is no problem passing the type to Joi to help infer what keys are allowed for validation:

```
const basicSchema = Joi.object<Basic, true>({
  key: Joi.string().min(1).required()
});
```

Now, deleting `key` or adding any other field to basicSchema makes typescript complain, which is what I want. However, I cannot find any way of creating a new schema, which extends this schema, that still helps me with the types for the extended schema.

```
const userSchema = basicSchema.keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().min(1).required()
})
```

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'firstName' does not exist in type 'PartialSchemaMap<Basic>'
```

There seems to be no way of passing `User` to keys because it doesn't accept generic types. I have multiple interfaces that extend the Basic interface so it would be really nice to have the Joi schemas do the same while keeping type safety.

Anyone got an idea on how to implement this?

Comment: I think `alternative`

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

Please use append() method of a Joi object schema to combine and re-use Typescript types.
Please find your code example below and let me know if you have any questions.

`const userSchema = basicSchema.append<User>({ firstName: Joi.string().required() })`

Comment: Thanks! This works, but only for rejecting incorrect properties. It does not warn about missing properties. I could for example pass an empty object as the appended schema.